What does 'den Freistaat Bayern' in this sentence refer to?
I came across the following sentence on wikipedia:

Als Ordnungszelle oder Ordnungszelle des Reiches bezeichneten
ultra-konservative, reaktionäre und völkisch-nationalistische Kreise
den Freistaat Bayern in den der Weimarer Republik, als dessen
Regierungen eine dezidiert gegen die Errungenschaften der
Novemberrevolution gerichtete, restaurative Politik betrieben.

in which the phrase 'den Freistaat Bayern' confuses me. My understanding is that Ordnungszelle / Ordnungszelle des Reiches denoted the ultra-konservative, reaktionäre und völkisch-nationalistische Kreise. But what is 'den Freistaat Bayern' here referring to? If it's the ultra-konservative, reaktionäre und völkisch-nationalistische Kreise in the state Bayern, then shouldn't it be ultra-konservative, reaktionäre und völkisch-nationalistische Kreise im Freistaat Bayern?

The sentence isn't actually grammatical. What is "in den der Weimarer Republik"? There seems to be something missing in that fragment. Yet another example of wikis' days of glory being in the past.

In a previous version of the article, there was a "ersten Jahren" between "in den" and "der Weimarer Republik".

@Raketenolli and currently it is just "in der Weimarer Republik"

@HagenvonEitzen I know, I made that edit.

It is the object "etwas" in etwas bezeichnen. To rephrase in standard order:

Ultra-konservative, reaktionäre und völkisch-nationalistische Kreise bezeichneten den Freistaat Bayern als Ordnungszelle oder Ordnungszelle des Reiches...

In the general pattern (subject) describes (object1) as (object2), the components are

subject: (...) Kreise
predicate: bezeichnen
object1: den Freistaat Bayern
object2: als Ordnungszelle

Your quote then has an error in the following temporal clause, the "den" must be eliminated:

...in der Weimarer Republik, als dessen Regierungen...Politik betrieben.


I don't know if I understand your question too easy.
Just in case you don't understand the expression "Freistaat Bayern"
Freistaat is only another name for Republik. So "Freistaat Bayern" is the "Republik Bavaria".
Please Note: Don't say "Republik Bayern" in German. Bavarians are proud of having a "Freistaat".
Some sources:

Bayern wurde zum Freistaat erklärt

Source: Wikipedia Bayern - Erster_Weltkrieg_und_Ende_der_Monarchie
Also https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freistaat_Bayern has a redirect to the Bayern-article.
And an official website:
https://www.bayern.de/der-freistaat/
They translate themself as Free State of Bavaria

The boiled-down version of the sentence is

Als Ordnungszelle bezeichneten (gewisse) Kreise den Freistaat Bayern

Which basically works similar to a sentence like "x is y" but comparing things (x and y) in the eyes of the subject "x is called by someone y" where x and y are here in Akkusativ case:

what they call it: Als Ordnungszelle oder Ordnungszelle des Reiches

who calls it: ultra-konservative, reaktionäre und völkisch-nationalistische Kreise

whom they call it: den Freistaat Bayern in den der Weimarer Republik


describing the circumstance / time further in the subordinate clause: als dessen Regierungen eine dezidiert gegen die Errungenschaften der Novemberrevolution gerichtete, restaurative Politik betrieben.
The basic construction of the verb "bezeichnen" is:

Jemand (Nom.) bezeichnet jemanden (Akk) als irgendwas (Akk)

